# Get contents of enum to a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, enums

I am trying  to convert my Items from Enum  to a dropdownlist .Please help

```
public enum Colors{ red,blue,green,yellow,orange,white,black,Teal,Custom }


 @Html.DropDownList("SelectedColourId", Model.ColourList, "(Select one Color)")
```

My ViewModel is below

```
  myPageViewModel:BasicViewModel
    {
 .....
     public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ColourList{ get; set; }
.........
    }
```

I am tried  something like

```
myViewModel.ColourList = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Colors)).ToArray()
                .Select(e => new SelectListItem() { Text = e.item, Value = e.itemindex });
```

But I don't know how to get itemText and its correesponding Index .Its throwing errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller, initialize the **ColourList** array using the Enum **GetNames** static method and Linq:

```
myPageViewModel.ColourList = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Colors))
    .Select(c => new SelectListItem() { Text = c, Value = c })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: @Millar gah, forgot you can't set the values in the constructor.  The above should work now.

Comment: But is there a way I can get Index of the item in palce of Value ?

Comment: @Millar sure, just use **Value = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), c)**

Answer (score 0):

to add the option in dropdown from enum use the below code:

```
   foreach (DropDownEnum enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DropDownEnum)))

        {

            model.SortOptions.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = enumValue.ToString(),
                Value = url+enumValue.ToString(),
                Selected = false

            });

        }
```